# Making a node affected by gravity has no affect; Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So, I am trying to make a simple game using Sprite Kit and Swift. In my game, I have obstacles that fall from the sky. They are small circles. Here is my code for the circles:

```
func createObstacle(){

    var ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 20 )
    var width = UInt32(self.frame.width)
    var random_number = arc4random_uniform(width)
    ball.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(random_number), frame.height)
    ball.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    ball.glowWidth = 1.0
    ball.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    self.addChild(ball)
}
```

It is fairly simple. However, this line

```
ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
```

does not seem to actually affect the node. This does not do anything, and there is no gravitational pull visually shown in the simulator. I have no idea why this isn't working. Does anybody know why?

**Edit to code:**

```
func createObstacle(){

    var ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 20 )
    var width = UInt32(self.frame.width)
    var random_number = arc4random_uniform(width)
    ball.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(random_number), frame.height)
    ball.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    ball.glowWidth = 1.0
    ball.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    self.addChild(ball)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't added an `SKPhysicsBody` to your `SKShapeNode`, therefore `ball.physicsBody` is `nil` and `affectedByGravity` isn't set.

To add a physics body you could do the following:

```
ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
```

Now you can set `affectedByGravity`:

```
ball.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
```

**Edit:**

The `CGVector` for `physicsWorld.gravity` should be:

```
// Note the minus sign.
physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -9.8)
```

Comment: Where are you setting the physics body? You need to make sure you do it before setting `affectedByGravity`.

Comment: I added your first line of code right above the second (where ...gravity=true)

Comment: I just tested the code and everything works...can you post your new code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77668/discussion-between-abakersmith-and-ihaveaquestion).

Comment: Have you ensured that the physicsWorld gravity is of a valid value?

Comment: under didMoveToView(), I have: '        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0,9.8)'. Does that work?

Comment: Shouldn't it be -9.8 for it to fall from the sky?

Comment: you need to put `self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self` in your didMove(toView:) method